# Apps is using high CPU usage than others normal webview

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

**EDIT :** Problem solved , "memory leak" was causes by one of the javascript below that keep on running in the HTML background that the rendering is using high CPU usage:

(so if anyone can help me fix this javascript leak are welcome too.)

```
var cog = new Image();
function init() {
cog.src = 'data';
                setInterval(draw,10);
            }
            var rotation = 0;
            function draw(){
                var ctx = document.getElementById('text').getContext('2d');
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
                ctx.save();
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,27,27);
                ctx.translate(13.5,13.5); 
                rotation +=1;
                ctx.rotate(rotation*Math.PI/64);
                ctx.translate(-13.5,-13.5);
                ctx.drawImage(cog,0,0);
                ctx.restore();
            }
            init();
```

Webview is using high CPU usage than others. Normal webview apps and the CPU usage won't drop to 0%. When I see at the Task Manager the application will highlighted in red and got killed by Android.

The CPU usage will be around 15+% to 27+%

Is it memory leak or its normal ?

Image :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was a memory leak you may see that your memory usage is grow. This situation can be explained that JS actions use many resources on this app.

Comment: I just checked again, the RAM and CPU usage is growing,but not too fast, and my javascript I only use JQuery and JQuery mobile , and its from local HTML and it does not perform any internet connection. So it's coding problem?

Comment: I guess it's a javascript engine bug, but you can test another ways to your app logic.

Comment: Ok thanks , after few hours of debug and checking and I found out that the problem is the one of the Javascript on that page is causing the memory leak.